# Laravel Rest API Login with Google

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel REST API to allow users to login with Google and Facebook so I used
Laravel Socialite My code

```
public function index(){
    return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
}
```

Service.php

```
 'google' => [
    'client_id' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret' =>'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET',
    'redirect' =>,
],
```

is it nessecory to add a redirect url here? since I only creating a rest api? if its needed how i can add?

the Error I'm getting is

```
    GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code"
}
```

Comment: Google sends back a payload after requesting OAUTH. The payload contains a code object that you are supposed to send as headers along with the callback route on Socialite.

Comment: @workservice can You explain it as answer?

Comment: Can you try to add your desired url at the redirect first? + This is a nice tutorial i have followed long time ago for the google auth: https://appdividend.com/2018/04/11/laravel-google-login-tutorial/